# Lower cpu performance in Linux

Tags: linux, performance, cpu

I have a problem with my CPU performance in Linux. I have a laptop, Toshiba Satellite C660-101.

Despite the fact that the CPU works perfectly fine in Windows 7, Linux has some serious issues.

Specifically, for some reason, the CPU is really slow. It is not the first time I am using Linux, I have Ubuntu in my desktop PCs. I have tried various distributions on my laptop like openSUSE (Gnome), Fedora (Xfce), Ubuntu (unity), and I always have the same problem.

I think it is something with the kernel, but I want your knowledge.

Comment: How do you determine that the CPU is slow?

Comment: Applications and file system operations are very slow in comparison with windows. I have some common applications for both operating systems(firefox,steam etc) and the performance difference is huge.

Comment: I heard that Windows runs more efficiently than Linux.

Comment: You can use `top` to see if a process is misbehaving and using all your cpu.

Comment: I tried some other programs to test my cpu performance, and unfortunately I noticed that only roughly 60% of the cpu is in use.

Comment: @Bit , can you run `lscpu` to check if the cpu is recognized properly and clock speed. Also `top` to check resources consuming processes.

Answer (score 5):

This is common problem on laptops. Your OS may have been configured to power saving mode.
Here are instructions how to change it:

Check your current CPU frequency:

```
    cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"
```

And check it with your CPU model frequency.

List your current *CPU scaling governors* for each core:

```
    cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

If it is `powersave` you are on the right track.

Then print out all available governors with this command:

```
    cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
```

Your output should looks like `conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance`. To change it you should set *performance* or *ondemand* governor.

Launch this as root:

```
    for gov in $(ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor)
    do
      echo "performance" > $gov
    done
```

Check CPU frequency again. It should match your real CPU model freq.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Firstly, I got the conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance as a result. But the for loop give me an syntax error near unexpected token `>' (i changed gov after for as $gov).